# High CPU utilization - cloudservice.exe

Tags: cloud, apache-cloudstack

We have Citrix Cloud Portal Business Manager (CPBM v2.3) and Citrix Cloud Portal (CCP v4.5).
Within the guest VM, we have installed a software to manage/re-set the passwords i.e. CloudInstanceManager.msi

http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/328840-link-to-cloudinstancemanagermsi-in-documentation-is-broken/

http://cloudstack-administration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates/_password.html

After installing this software on Windows Server 2008 R2, the process cloudservice.exe utilizes 100% CPU slowing down the server.
Server is up to date with Windows patches, also downloaded the latest version of CloudInstanceManager.msi from Apache cloudstack.

This process is required to be deployed in all guest VMs to re-set the passwords.

Can someone help me to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure where the cloudservice.exe logs to, but have you checked Event Viewer for anything?

Also, check that you're able to reach your VR (usually the DHCP host) on port 8080 from the VM, it might be stuck in a loop trying to fetch the password or something like that.